# Open URL from Bash script

Tags: bash, url, lynx

I have a text file

```
Google.com
Youtube.com
Gmail.com
Yahoo.com
```

I am trying to open them with Lynx. Here is the thesis.

I will store all of those links at a txt file, say links.txt and then I need to open them with Lynx and then terminate Lynx by using kill.

Here the code I wrote but its not correct

```
for i in links.txt
do
lynx $i
sleep 10
pkill lynx
done
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After several iterations...

```
for url in $(cat links.txt); do
    timeout 10 lynx "$url"
done
```

Lynx is blocking (and has to be to work) so sleeping doesn't work properly and it also tries to nab stdin which makes piping things "interestingly" difficult. [See here for iterating lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash).

Lynx can be a bit annoying with its prompts for allowing cookies. You can either change its settings if it's a problem or you can pass in the `-accept_all_cookies` flag, like so:

```
for url in $(cat links.txt); do
     timeout 10 lynx -accept_all_cookies "$url"
done
```

Today I learned about the `timeout` command, so I'm happy.

---

To print a status at the end, the only way I can see how is to check the URL is okay separately, like so:

```
for url in $(cat links.txt); do
     timeout 10 lynx -accept_all_cookies "$url"
     if [[ $(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' "$url") -eq "200" ]]; then
        echo "Getting $url successful"
     else
        echo "Getting $url unsuccessful"
     fi
done
```

Comment: Seems to be i gave you some complex task. Right.

Comment: I just hope you're learning as much about Bash as I am :)

Comment: I think yes @Oli. 

Comment: +1 for `timeout` and `-accept_all_cookies`. Today I learned about both of them :)

Comment: @Oli here could you provide some more support that, if lynx accessed that URL successfully then echo "yes " else echo " no" .

Comment: @rajagenupula I've expanded it a little further.

Answer (score 1):

In your script the lynx call locks the terminal and it will never call sleep 10 and pkill because lynx exits just when you hit "Q".

So i whould prefer something different. Why don't you use wget. 
Something like this:

```
for url in $(cat links.txt); do
  wget -qO- $URL
  sleep 1
done
```

wget exits after downloading the link. Lynx is more like an interactive console browser (it locks the terminal), it's not made for scripts.

Comment: THank you. I am actually off to pc right now . I will let you know.